# How to ensure recieved text is displayed over multiple lines?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, textarea

Currently have a `textarea` that receives a message and displays it to a user.

However currently when it receives it, if the message is longer than it's border, it keeps displaying the text on one line **outside** the right hand border.

I would like the text to start on a new line when it reaches the border. How can I do so?

Below is the current code for the text area.

**Text area:**

```
echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'name','rows'=>3,'cols'=>100,'wrap'=>'hard','value'=>""));
```

Comment: What is the HTML for the textarea? View the source and make sure it's OK.

Comment: how do I do so? thanks

Comment: When the page has loaded, go to "View > Page Source" and see what the form_textarea method is outputting.

Answer (score 0):

`width: 50px; word-wrap: break-word;` should do the trick, of course set your own width

Comment: I guess you just need to add `,'style'=>'word-wrap: break-word;'` to it if I'm right.